# If $G$ is a nonabelian finite simple group, does $G$ contain a maximal subgroup which is not abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Follow [this link](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/a-nonabelian-group-whose-every-proper-subgroup-is-abelian-is-not-simple) a nonabelian group whose every proper subgroup is abelian is not simple. So if $G$ is a nonabelian finite simple group, does $G$ contain a maximal subgroup which is not abelian?

Comment: Yes, that follows directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the lemma in your link, if $G$ is simple and nonabelian, then $G$ has a nonabelian proper subgroup $H$. Every proper subgroup is contained in some maximal subgroup, so $H$ is contained in a maximal subgroup $M$.  All subgroups of abelian groups are abelian, so $M$ must be nonabelian.